# How to reference a function within a function usort

Tags: php, sorting, usort

I'm trying to call a function using `usort`, however, I get an error back that the class does not have a method.

```
$awards = usort ($q->posts, array($this, '_mt_latest_award_sort'));
```

The setup is currently:

```
namespace Test\Theme
class Shortcodes extends Theme
{
    // ...
    // this is the function I am trying to call on
    function _mt_latest_award_sort($value1, $value2) 
    {
        // ...
        // code to do the sorting 
        // ...
    }
    // ...
    $awards = usort ($q->posts, array($this, '_mt_latest_award_sort');
    // ...
}
```

When I change the `usort` to reference my "awards" function

```
$awards = usort ($q->posts, array($this, 'awards'));
```

it throws back an error that my functions within the public awards function have already been declared.

How to I point to the `_mt_latest_award_sort` function correctly?

Comment: You have no `_mt_latest_award_sort` function present in your posted code. Do you mean `_mt_latest_award`?

Comment: If you wish you can make it a class function instead (just like `awards()` is), or you can enclose the function declaration in a `if (!function_exists('_mt_latest_award_sort')) { }` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is in an other function, try to declare your function in the class instead

for example :

```
class C
{
    public function Fa()
    {
        function Fc()
        {
            ...
        }
        ...
        $this->Fb(); // it works C::Fb is a function
        $this->Fc(); // it doesn't work, there is no C::Fc function
        ...
    }

    function Fb()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not support nested functions.

This is a common mistake / misconception, because the code below appears to work:

```
function foo() {
    function bar() {
        echo 'Hello!';
    }
    bar();
    bar();
    bar();
}
```

However, this is not actually defining a nested function, it's just defining a global function `bar` whenever `foo()` is run. You can test this by running `foo()` twice - the first time, `function bar` will be defined, then run 3 times; the second time, you'll get a fatal error, because you're trying to define the same function twice.

You either need to define your function as a separate method of the class:

```
class Shortcodes extends Theme
{
    public function awards()
    {
       ...
        $awards = usort($q->posts, array($this, '_mt_latest_award_sort'));
        ...
    }

    private function _mt_latest_award_sort($value1, $value2) 
    {
        ...
        //code to do the sorting 
        ...
    }
}
```

Or, use an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```
class Shortcodes extends Theme
{
    public function awards()
    {
        ...
        $awards = usort ($q->posts, function($value1, $value2) 
        {
            ...
            //code to do the sorting 
            ...
        });
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, moving the function out into a separate method of the class worked.

Answer (score 0):

When the method "awards" is called, there's an attempt to declare the function "_mt_latest_award_sort".

With the `$awards = usort ($q->posts, array($this, '_mt_latest_award_sort');` implementation, this would also fail the same way:

```
$shortcode = new Shorcodes;
$shortcode->awards(); // "_mt_latest_award_sort" is declared
$shortcode->awards(); // attempted to redeclare "_mt_latest_award_sort"
```

Just because you're declaring a named function inside another function, it does not mean its scope is not global.

This should solve your problem:

```
class Shortcodes extends Theme
{
    private $posts = array();

    // ...

    private function _mt_latest_award_sort($value1, $value2) {
         // ...
    }

    public function awards()
    {
         // ...
        $awards = usort($this->posts, array($this, '_mt_latest_award_sort'));
         // ...
    }
}
```

You could also use an anonymous function:

```
$awards = usort($this->posts, function($value1, $value2) {
    // ...
});
```